# How to access react-app build from local file url ("file:///"), without using any HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

My requirement is that I have to use my react SPA by loading local file URL as follows

```
file:///C:/react/build/index.html
```

without using any HTTP-server.

In this scenario, it's working with HTTP server correctly,
but in the case of local file URL access, only initial component working correctly but Routing is not working.

it's giving following types of error in chrome-

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A
>   history state object with URL 'file:///C:/react/build/Aboutus' cannot
>   be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL
>   'file:///C:/react/build/index.html'.

and in firefox-

> > SecurityError: The operation is insecure. 1.d30e17d6.chunk.js:1 push/< createBrowserHistory.js:153 confirmTransitionTo
> >     createTransitionManager.js:33 push createBrowserHistory.js:146
> >     e/i.handleClick Link.js:99 p/< react-dom.production.min.js:49 p
> >     react-dom.production.min.js:45 P/< react-dom.production.min.js:73 P
> >     react-dom.production.min.js:72 S react-dom.production.min.js:168 E
> >     react-dom.production.min.js:158 j react-dom.production.min.js:232 Tn
> >     react-dom.production.min.js:1712 Za react-dom.production.min.js:5451
> >     Dt react-dom.production.min.js:660 Sn react-dom.production.min.js:1754
> >     Fa react-dom.production.min.js:5479 Cn
> >     react-dom.production.min.js:1731 Cn self-hosted:1018:17

please suggest me some solution or give me some sample code. and please don't suggest to use any HTTP server method, because in this case, I have to do it without using any HTTP server.

I am using create-react-app method with react-router v4

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Pursuhothaman, the duplicate you linked is not actually a duplicate for this question. The title of this question is just not complete.

Comment: @nbokmans I read the full question and then found this would be a good match. Why do you think so?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman your suggested answer is not what I am looking for. as I already said, the initial component is loading fine, but it's giving above error for subsequent routing in my app using react-router. So please suggest me a solution or remove duplicate flag

Comment: @Smaranjit Ah, I thought it was evident from the other answers. **React Router doesn't work on file protocol.** See this: [Viewing over file:// protocol · Issue #3591 · facebook/create-react-app · GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3591).

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman please remove the duplicate flag from this question, as this will help other to reach here.

Comment: @Smaranjit It's gonna be closed as a dupe as this is not possible. Anyway, I have reopened the question. Have fun.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman thanks for your response, actually after visiting your link, I tried several solutions provided there, and now it's working for my specific situation. I have also posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: I would like to have a comment before downvoting this question. :)

Comment: Alternative approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64129714/75129

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this problem could be solved using [`{HashRouter}`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md) or [`{MemoryRouter}`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) instead of using `{BrowserRouter}`.

and then you can access the SPA from local file protocol `("file:///xyz/index.html")`, and your router link will work fine with react-router for local file URL.

```
 - import { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"; //remove this line
 + import { HashRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"; //try this line

or
--
+ import { MemoryRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"; //try this line
```

also add the following line to package.json for relative linking.

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That one-word change from "Browser" to "Hash" fixed everything for my offline SPA to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and used the [memory router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) to make it work since it did not actually change the url. Also I changed the absolute route to a relative route configuring the package.json with `"homepage": ".",` which it is not officially supported by react